# How do I loop through a condition to assign a new value to a different attribute?

Tags: ruby, loops, where-clause

I'm trying to use text from the :name attribute to assign a unit_type in a new array of hashes.

Here's my data

```
class Unit
  attr_accessor :name
  attr_accessor :imported_id
  attr_accessor :country
  attr_accessor :unit_type

  raw_stuff = [{:old_id=>576, :name=>"16th Armored Division (USA) "}, {:old_id=>578, :name=>"20th Armored Division (USA)"}, {:old_id=>759, :name=>"27th Armoured Brigade (UK)"}, {:old_id=>760, :name=>"- 13th/18th Royal Hussars"}, {:old_id=>761, :name=>"- East Riding of Yorkshire Yeomanry "}, {:old_id=>762, :name=>"- Staffordshire Yeomanry "}, {:old_id=>769, :name=>"A I R B O R N E "}, {:old_id=>594, :name=>"1st Airborne Division (UK)"}, {:old_id=>421, :name=>"6th Airborne Division (UK)"}]

  units = []

  raw_stuff.each do |unit_hash|
   u = Unit.new
   u.name = unit_hash[:name].sub("-","").lstrip
   u.unit_type = unit_hash[:name].scan("Division")
   puts u.unit_type
   puts u.name
  end

end
```

This appropriately assigns "division" as the the unit_type.
However I cannot seems to assign anything else, like "brigade" for example.
Should i use if or where conditions?

```
When I use the following code:
  raw_stuff.each do |unit_hash|
   u = Unit.new
   u.name = unit_hash[:name].sub("-","").lstrip
      if unit_hash[:name].scan("Division")
        u.unit_type = "Division"
      elsif unit_hash[:name].scan("Brigade")
        u.unit_hash = "Brigade"
      else
        u.unit_hash = nil
      end
   puts u.unit_type
   puts u.name
  end
```

I end up getting Divison assigned to EVERY unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cute one-liner:

```
u.unit_type = unit_hash[:name][/Division|Brigade/]
```

The bug in your code is that `scan` returns an empty array (`[]`) when it doesn't find anything, and an empty array is "truthy". The method you're looking for is `include?` My solution bypasses the conditional entirely by directly assigning the string search result (which can be `nil`) to the unit type.

Comment: I went with .include? in place of .scan because I'm going to be adding a lot more unit types.

Comment: Thanks - this is proving useful in my next attribute assignment

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if unit_hash[:name].include?("Division")
    u.unit_type = "Division"
  elsif unit_hash[:name].include?("Brigade")
    u.unit_type = "Brigade"
  else
    u.unit_type = nil
  end
```

Comment: I'm brand new to the site.  It looks like I need a rep level of at least 15.  I only got five right now